# boto3 send_bonus operation fails with ParameterValidationError

Tags: boto3, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to use `boto3` to send a bonus to a worker.

The documentation lists the following:

```
response = client.send_bonus(
    WorkerId='string',
    BonusAmount='string',
    AssignmentId='string',
    Reason='string',
    UniqueRequestToken='string'
)
```

This is my code:

```
connection.send_bonus(
    WorkerId=mturk_worker_id,
    AssignmentId=assignment_id,
    BonusAmount="0.5",
    Reason=reason
)
```

Here `mturk_worker_id` is a string:

```
IN : type(str(mturk_worker_id))
OUT: str
```

When trying to run my code I get:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ParameterValidationError) when calling the SendBonus operation: The value "A2CSGR33WTRXO0" is not valid for the parameter WorkerId. (1586868624734 s)
```

Comment: Additional info: the assignment was completed within the last 6 months

Comment: Was the assignment completed by the exact same worker id you're attempting to bonus?

Comment: @Trenton good question, but yes, it was.

Comment: I played around with things today and the only way I could recreate the error message you describe is if the worker id and assignment id are mismatched. That is, trying to bonus a worker for an assignment they didn't complete. Double check that isn't the problem, and if you're still having problems, open an AWS support ticket.

Comment: @Trenton I will get back to this next time I need to send a bonus. For now I used a round-about way of creating a hit that requires a qualification that's only assigned to the worker that required the bonus.